# Linker error while trying to compile OpenCv file with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, linker

I trying to compile some OpenCv functions and I included the cvhaartraining.h from the directory C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\haartraining.

I put on Project > 'Your Project Name' Properties... > Configuration Properties > Linker > Input >

all the .lib files in the opencv library:

```
"C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_highgui220d.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_core220d.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_ml220d.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_video220d.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_legacy220d.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_imgproc220d.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_objdetect220d.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_ts220.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_calib3d220d.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_contrib220d.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_features2d220d.lib"
 "C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_ffmpeg220d.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_flann220d.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_gpu220d.lib"
```

but it still won't link.

The error I get is:

```
vecToFiles.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cvShowVecSamples(char const *,int,int,double)" (?cvShowVecSamples@@YAXPBDHHN@Z) referenced in function _main
vecToFiles.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cvCreateTrainingSamplesFromInfo(char const *,char const *,int,int,int,int)" (?cvCreateTrainingSamplesFromInfo@@YAHPBD0HHHH@Z) referenced in function _main
vecToFiles.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cvCreateTestSamples(char const *,char const *,int,int,char const *,int,int,int,double,double,double,int,int,int)" (?cvCreateTestSamples@@YAXPBD0HH0HHHNNNHHH@Z) referenced in function _main
vecToFiles.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cvCreateTrainingSamples(char const *,char const *,int,int,char const *,int,int,int,double,double,double,int,int,int)" (?cvCreateTrainingSamples@@YAXPBD0HH0HHHNNNHHH@Z) referenced in function _main
vecToFiles\Debug\vecToFiles.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

I think Im missing some .lib file, but I dont know which file.
Ill appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

What extra lib files do you have? From googling it looks like it's compiled into a file called cvhaartraining.lib.

Comment: Hi, that's all the lib files I have in the OpenCv\lib. I also have cv.lib which is gor python and also viseoInput.lib in 3rdParty\lib. I tried them all and it won't work. I tried downloading cvhaartraining.lib and linking to it and I got the error "invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x88FF". all the .lib file are in opencv_XXXd.lib format. thank you for your help !

Comment: I think you will need to build the lib from cvhaartraining.cpp and cvhaartraining.h (and whatever else there might be). Does the program come with a makefile of any type?

Comment: yes it comes with makefile, i tried to build it but got some errors. do you think this is the solution ?

Comment: If you look in the makefile, it will show you all the different libraries needed for compiling. If there are any in that file that you don't have in your project, that may show you where the problem is.

Comment: OK, it solved. I reinstalled OpenCV, configured the program makefile (not just haartraining makefile) with cmake and new .lib files were added. one of them is opencv_haartraining_engine.lib. thank you !